# Rendered line on a flat plane

Tags: mesh

Can anyone tell me what the line is rendered on this flat plane and how to get rid of it please? Things I've already tried:

- Recreating topology around the holes using only quads as shown
- Looptools - flatten
- Scale in Z by zero

[image: Topology 1]

Edit:

I tried adding extra supporting edges, but I noticed I kept chasing the lines around. It is very dependent on the viewing angle of the render, see below for three slightly different angles. So I'm thinking there is something more fundamental going on. More info:

- I'm using the Measureit tool to add dimensions which requires the Blender Render engine according to a tutorial I followed
- There is no thickness to my plane (I'll try adding some)

[image: Topology 2]

Comment: In addition to the edges I suggested below, I would actually suggest adding edges anywhere you have a "T" junction.  It's possible that the mesh splits there, and thus in the render it makes a seam.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding these edges (shown in red)?

[image]

Comment: Hmm, nope, I'll give it a try! Thanks